Swagger request interceptor is not setting headers on final request
My API has CSRF protection enabled and I wanted to keep swagger's "Try out" feature working by adding a request interceptor that obtains the CSRF token and adds it to the request's headers.
I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to configure it. I can see the interceptor function is being called and the returned request object includes the x-csrf-token header. However when the request to the target endpoint is made the header is not included.
(req) => {
    fetch('/v1/antiforgery/token', {
        method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(res => {
        req.headers['x-csrf-token'] = res.headers.get('x-csrf-token');
    })

    return req;
}

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.UseRequestInterceptor("<JS code above>");
});

